# RxJs: how to maintain one WebSocket connection across multiple components?

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a chat application that consists of multiple components (e.g. one components holds a group list, another one contains messages, etc.), and when one component is opened another one must be closed.

So here is a service that I'm using to provide a webSocket connection:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatConnectionService {

  private _connection: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private window: WindowAbstract) { }

  public closeConnection(): void {
    this.connection.complete();
  }

  public send(msg: ChatRequest): void {
    this.connection.next(msg);
  }

  public messages(): Subject<any> {
    return this.connection;
  }

  private get connection(): Subject<any> {
    if (!this._connection || this._connection.closed) {
      this._connection = webSocket(`https/myapp/chat`);
    }

    return this._connection;
  }
}
```

And here is a usage example in `some.component.ts`:

```
  private messages$: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messages$ = this.chatConnectionService.messages()
      .subscribe(m => this.handleInboundMessage(m));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.messages$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Now the problem is that when I switch between components, once it gets unsubscribed when an old component being destroyed, a new subscription does not seem to be working, it does not send or received messages and does not produce any error as well.

But when I remove unsubscribe line it starts working, but keeps receiving messages using the old subscription as well, which is not what I really want.

So summarizing it all - I need to maintain one connection but having a possibility for multiple components to subscribe and unsubscribe as needed, is it possible to accomplish it with RxJs? Or what am I doing wrong? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Read very quickly, may not help but maybe make the service a singleton or maybe share replay could help

Comment: Are you sure that your Components actually share the same Service instance? When you declare a service for Dependency Injection in Angular, you have to specify the "scope" of the service. I do not see `providedIn: 'root'` in the Injectable decorator, which is the usual way to declare a Global service. So it is possible that your components have each their own private instance of the service. This does not explain the whole problem, but in any case it is important to make sure you share one single instance of the service among all Components.

Comment: I'm sure, it's declared in a module that contains the components

Comment: Could you create a minimal repo?

Comment: Where in your `ChatConnectionService` do you instantiate `connection`?

Comment: With `Subject`, late subscribers will not receive prior emissions.  If you want late subscribers to receive all prior emissions, you can use [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) instead.

Comment: RxJS provides a [`webSocket`](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket) subject that may interest you.

Comment: @BizzyBob Hi, thanks for the answer. Though, I'm already using it in the service `webSocket(`https/myapp/chat`)` and it is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just leave it here for someone who endup in the same situation.

You need at least one subscription running all the time so it doesn't close connection when you unsubscribe.

So here is what I did:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        multi: true,
        // subscribing establishes a connections
        useFactory: (chat: ChatConnectionService) => () => chat.messages$.subscribe(),
        deps: [ChatConnectionService]
    }
  ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Not so obvious pitfall here is that unsubscribing from `WebSocketSubject` and from an `Observable`, that was created by subscribing to the subject, have the same effect - it closes an active connection if it was the last subscription.

Comment: The reason for "You need at least one subscription running", is that you are using a cold observable, you should change it to a hot observable. hot observables don't need a subscriber to keep alive.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are giving components direct reference to the `WebSocketSubject` being returned from `webSocket('https/myapp/chat')`. If you invoke the `.unsubscribe()` method on `WebSocketSubject`, it closes the channel, which is why no other components detect messages.

Rather than doing getters, declare a public observable that is piped from the private `WebSocketSubject`.

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatConnectionService {

  public messages$ = Observable<any>; // Replace 'any' with WS response type.
  private connection: WebSocketSubject;

  constructor(private window: WindowAbstract) { 
    this.connection = webSocket(`https/myapp/chat`);
    this.messages$ = this.connection.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Your component will now be unsubscribing from the observable, rather than invoking the WebSocketSubject to unsubscribe from the channel.

---

**Update** After further review of the WebSocketSubject being instantiated by `webSocket()` I realized that `.asObservable()` isn't the best use case for your situation. Even if your components unsubscribe from the observable, the Subject is still receiving new data from the open WS channel.

```
this.messages$ = this.connection.multiplex(
  () => { 'send message to WS server to start' }, 
  () => { 'send message to WS server to stop' }, 
  (message) => true // filter messages by condition
);
```

You can declare an observable from your WebSocketSubject using the `multiplex()` method. It takes three parameters:

1. Function that declares the start message for WS.
2. Function that declares the end message for WS.
3. Function that filters messages

Now, whenever any component subscribes to `messages$`, it will trigger the start message, opening the channel for subscribers. When all observables unsubscribe from `messages$`, it sends the close signal halting any further messages.

This saves a lot of boilerplate for maintaining a singleton state for your WS.

Reference: https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/WebSocketSubject

Comment: Hi @digclo! Just wanted to give you a feedback. Regarding the multiplex suggestion, I think you misunderstood what it is for - it is when you have a different channels running through a single websocket connection. But my case is when I have just one channel and multiple subscribers. I've also tried what you suggested at first, it doesn't make any difference either. But what I figure out so far, is that if you keep at least one subscription active all the time it doesn't close the connection when the other component unsubscribes, probably it has to do with the rxjs implementation of websockets

Comment: A simpler approach would be to define `this.messages$ = this.connection.asObservable()`. What I was trying to do with using `multiplex()` is to prevent you from having an active websocket running in the background while you app is in some state that doesn't need that data.